# Grails call Controller method from View

Tags: grails, loops, methods, view, controller

I have a quick question for grails. I have a view page that iterates over an array of objects to display them. The HTML/Grails tag code looks like this:

```
<g:each in="${ICFList}" status="i" var="icf">
<tr>
    <td>${icf.printName?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
    <td>${icf.activeNote?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
</tr>
</g:each>
```

This code works and displays what I need. However, I don't want to store a printName variable inside my icf object anymore. the object also contains a one character code to identify it, and I have a method that looks up the printName value based on the code. Basically, my question is this:

Is there a way to do something like this

```
<td>${icf.getNameFromCode(${icf.code})}</td>
```

without having to store the name anywhere?
The getNameFromCode method is defined in the controller object for this particular view, but I can't figure out how to access it from the gsp. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can call a controller method from the view.

What I'd suggest is either to move the `getNameFromCode` to the domain class or implement the logic in a taglib and use a custom tag to display your data. Which option to choose depends on whether that method refers to something that's intrinsic to the model or something that's tied to the view.

The latest [Getting started with Grails screencast](http://www.grails.org/screencast/show/28) explains how to create and use custom tags.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo I gave the tagLibs a shot and it worked perfectly

Comment: Those field names feel much more like model's fields, I advice that you make the domain/whatever class fields and use a Model.

Answer (score 7):

Answering the question formally, you can use [g:include](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/include.html):

```
<g:include controller="book" action="list" />
```

*though the fields of single entity feel so much more like a Model*.

Comment: Noting that the method should be static (in this example 'list')

Answer (score 1):

It can also be achieved by making AJAX calls to this controller, but I think Gustavo's answer is what you are looking for.