# Call Method in Controller from GSP in Grails 3

Tags: grails

I am trying to call a method defined in my controller from a GSP page. I have done this exact same thing before in previous versions of Grails before 3.

In my gsp:

```
<%@ page import="com.me.MyController" %>

<% 
    def cont = grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass("com.me.MyController").newInstance()
%>
${cont.getInfo('string')}
```

And in my controller:

```
def getInfo(String id){
        return "stuff"
    }
```

I am currently getting the error that the controller does not have a method called `getInfo()` that accepts a string type, then suggests other methods that are no where near the method that I am trying to call. So did something change in `Grails 3` or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling a controller like that. That's not how controllers are suppose to be used. If you need to do something like that create a tag library that makes use of a service to fetch/return data to your GSP.

```
package some.package.example

class LookupTagLib {
  def myService

  static namespace = "custom"
  // use returnObjectForTags for Grails 3.x and above.
  static returnObjForTags = ["doLookupThing"]

  def doLookupThing = { attrs ->
    return myService.doLookup(attrs.someParam)
  }
}
```

And then in your GSP:

```
${custom.doLookupThing([someParam: 'string'])}
```

Comment: I tried this, but using `return` returns nothing. I used `out <<` which returned a string, but I need an array.

Comment: Did you set `returnObjForTags` in your tag library? The above example works. I've used it when needed and will work for your situation as well. If you can't get that to work then I would recommend opening another question since this one has been answered and this is now a new question.

Comment: If it's not working for me, you didn't answer my question.

Comment: I found the issue. Your syntax does not work in Grails 3. It's now `returnObjectForTags` per the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#tagReturnValue)

Comment: @JustinFoley nice catch. I've updated the answer to include this useful information. Glad you got it working now.

Comment: Just for the sake of referencing, for earlier versions look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6354444/1572286